# C# SQLite Windows CE "Out of memory exception."

Tags: c#, multithreading, sqlite, compact-framework

So I keep having a problem where I'm getting an error stating I'm out of memory. I have a main thread and a worker thread that uses a file called SqlLiteAssetCommands.cs which contains some commands such as the following.

```
    Database newConnection;
    /// <summary>
    /// Open connection return the SQLlight command
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private SQLiteCommand openConnection()
    {
        newConnection = new Database();
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand();
        try
        {
            newConnection.OpenConnection();
            command = newConnection.Connection.CreateCommand();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.Error("Could not open connection.", e);
        }
        return command;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Close connection to the local database.
    /// </summary>
    private void closeConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            newConnection.CloseConnection();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.Error("Could not close the connection.", e);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a transaction.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Returns the new transaction that is created.</returns>
    private SQLiteTransaction getTransaction()
    {
        SQLiteTransaction sqlTransaction = null;
        try
        {
            sqlTransaction = newConnection.Connection.BeginTransaction();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.Error("Could not get sqlTransaction.", e);
        }
        return sqlTransaction;
    }

    #region Asset Database commands

    /// <summary>
    /// Delete all rows from sqlite database.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Returns "Completed" if successful.</returns>
    public String deleteAllRows()
    {
        SQLiteCommand command = openConnection();
        String status = null;
        using (SQLiteTransaction sqlTransaction = getTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                command.CommandText = @"DELETE FROM Asset";
                using (SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        reader.Read();
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                }
                status = "Completed";
                sqlTransaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                log.Error("Could not delete all assets.", e);
            }
        }
        closeConnection();
        return status;
    }
```

So my open connection is called from a different file called Database.cs and the error is caught on the open function stating I'm out of memory. I'm not sure what I need to do to keep this from happening as I cannot force the error to occur. This time happened when I was trying to force an error to show so I could screen-shoot it and finally got tired of trying and waited without doing anything. Then it just happened due to my worker thread.

```
    public SQLiteConnection Connection = new SQLiteConnection();
    // Define a static logger variable so that it references the name of your class
    private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Database));

    // Try to open a connection to the sqlLight database.
    public void OpenConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            Connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + Utilities.Global.SqlLiteDB);
            Connection.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception eErr)
        {
            log.Error("Error connecting to database.", eErr);
            MessageBox.Show("Error connecting to database.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.None, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
        }
    }
    // Close the database connection.
    public void CloseConnection()
    {
        Connection.Close();
    }
}
```

[image]

Anything I can do to fix this or improve my code would be helpful.

Here is the code for my worker thread since this may be the root cause of the problem.

```
class AssettoServerThread
{
    // Define a static logger variable so that it references the name of your class
    private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(AssettoServerThread));

    WebServicesSyncAsset syncAsset = new WebServicesSyncAsset();
    SqlLightAssetCommands assetToSql = new SqlLightAssetCommands();


    /////////////////////// Variables //////////
    private volatile bool _shouldStop = false;

    // SINGLETON ///////////////////////////////
    private static AssettoServerThread instance = null;

    public static AssettoServerThread GetInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new AssettoServerThread();

        return instance;
    }
    // /////////////////////////////////////////

    // this variable will hold the condition of ServicesAvailable set by the worker thread
    private bool areServicesAvailable = false;

    private bool AreServicesAvailable
    {
        get { return areServicesAvailable; }
        set { areServicesAvailable = value; }
    }

    // This method will be called when the thread is stopped. 
    public void RequestStop()
    {
        _shouldStop = true;
    }

    // Create a worker thread and then check if the webservices are available.
    // If available then set ServicesAvailable to true and begin sending updated assets to the server.
    public void DoThreading()
    {
        // Continuous loop
        while (!_shouldStop)
        {
            try
            {
                // Creates an HttpWebRequest for the specified URL.
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(AppConfigSettings.serverIP);
                // Set some reasonable limits on resources used by this request
                request.KeepAlive = false;
                request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
                // Sends the HttpWebRequest and waits for a response.
                using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                {
                    //request.Abort();
                    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        areServicesAvailable = true;
                    }
                    // Releases the resources of the response.
                    response.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                areServicesAvailable = false;
                log.Info("Website is currently not accessible. Therefore the services are not accessible.", ex);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                areServicesAvailable = false;
                log.Info("Website is currently not accessible. Therefore the services are not accessible.", ex);
            }

            // If the webservices are available then run else sleep for 30 seconds.
            if (AreServicesAvailable)
            {
                try
                {
                    assetToSql.AddAssetsToServer();
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    log.Error("Could not add asset to server.", e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Then it just happened due to my worker thread.

Your threading code might be relevant, then.

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing was instead of having two threads I made it into one worker thread and made sure it never overlapped. I also added a connection pool to my SQLlite database. I also changed the images on my project and deleted all unnecessary images to save space. I don't know what fixed it but this worked for me.